# How to scraping JSON that contains a specific string In Javascript with Xpath

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, xpath, evaluatejavascript

I have a HTML data like this.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{ "name": "apple", "price": 100 }</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">{ "name": "banana", "price": 200 }</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">{ "name": "orange", "price": 300 }</script>
```

How can I scrape Json data which contains "banana" with Xpath.

For example, the javascript code below can scrape JSON containing banana. But it's just scraping only the second JSON.

```
    const htmlString = res;
    const doc = new DOMParser();
    const string = doc.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
    const result = string.evaluate('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]', string, null, 6, null);
    const character = result.snapshotItem(2);
    console.log(character);
```

In the code below, the variable is Null.

```
    const htmlString = res;
    const doc = new DOMParser();
    const string = doc.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
    const result = string.evaluate('//script[contains(text(), "banana")]', string, null, 6, null);
    const character = result.snapshotItem(1);
    console.log(character);
```

The image of the goal is { "name": "banana", "price": 200 } .

Answer (score 1):

The index should be `0`, since you are targeting exactly which one you want.

```
const character = result.snapshotItem(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why xpath?

```js
const obj = [...document.querySelectorAll("script[type='application/ld+json']")]
  .map(script => JSON.parse(script.textContent))
  .filter((item)=>item.name==="banana")
  
console.log(obj[0])
```

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">{ "name": "apple", "price": 100 }</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">{ "name": "banana", "price": 200 }</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">{ "name": "orange", "price": 300 }</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get there with:

```
result = string.evaluate('//script[contains(text(), "banana")]/text()', string, null, 6, null),
character = result.snapshotItem(0).nodeValue;
console.log(character);
```